# Which group does germanium belong to?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, atoms, orbitals

$\mathrm{Z= 32}$

$\mathrm{1s^2\ 2s^2p^6\ 3s^2p^6d^{10}\ 4s^2p^2}$

According to me it belongs the $\mathrm{IV\ B}$ group since it has the $\mathrm{d}$ completed, but it belongs to $\mathrm{IV\ A}$. But we know that in the $\mathrm{A}$ group only the $\mathrm{s}$ and $\mathrm{p}$ elements belong. Why does this happen?

Comment: My periodic table has Ge as a IV B element, with IV A being Ti, Zr, and Hf. So I'm not sure which periodic table you are perusing.

Answer (score 2):

According to the IUPAC, the is not such thing as groups IV A and B anymore.
All the elements you are analyzing belong to the 14th group of the periodic table, each one in one period, from the 2nd to the 6th.

In regards to your other question, you need to look for a trend on the elements of the group.
What happens as you go down the group?
I think you've already figured out that the number of electrons around the nucleus significantly increases, and this has an important effect on the radius of the atom.

Comment: Here is a good periodic table, and the one you should be using: [IUPAC periodic table](http://www.iupac.org/fileadmin/user_upload/news/IUPAC_Periodic_Table-1May13.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for the link.  Now I can come into the 21st century...